# Firebase Big query each day session duration of each user all event for last few days

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

i want a query for  session duration of each user in firebase analytics bigquery  . Tried this query but what we are getting is  day a starting event - day ending event , which is 22 - 23hrs for some user.

SELECT user_id as user,
event_date,
event_name,
COUNT(*) AS event_count,
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), MIN(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), SECOND) AS SessionDuration
FROM
-- Replace table name.
`table_name*`
WHERE
-- Replace date range.
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210917' AND '20210920'
GROUP BY 1, 2,3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want a query for  session duration of each user in firebase analytics bigquery